# How to use let to define a new set of data within a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that represents all the Ingredients for a Recipe

```
public class ViewRecipe
{
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }
    public double UnitWeight { get; set; }
    public double TotalWeight { get; set; }

    public ViewRecipe() { }
    public ViewRecipe(string _RecipeName, string _IngredientName, double _UnitWeight, double _TotalWeight)
    {
        RecipeName = _RecipeName;
        IngredientName = _IngredientName;
        UnitWeight = _UnitWeight;
        TotalWeight = _TotalWeight;
    }
}(in reality there are a LOT more data members like quantity, weight, etc....)
```

The actual dataset is a List called ViewRecipeSummary and it looks like this:

```
RecipeName IngredientName
1          A
1          B
1          C
2          D
2          E
3          A
3          Z
```

I have an existing query which finds an INGRIDENT (recipeGroup.Key) and I need to now do the following:

1- find all recipes that have that ingredient

2- return all rows from my data for those recipes

And I need to then use this inside my query (so it needs to be with a LET or something)

Lets assume I am looking for all recipes that share ingredient A, I expect the end result of my LET (based on the data I show above) to look exactly like this:

```
RecipeName IngredientName
1          A
1          B
1          C
3          A
3          Z
```

So for any recipe that has ingredient A (1 and 3) return all rows of those recipes so I have all the ingredients I need.
And this should be in the same form as my ViewRecipe class (not some new {RecipeName, List}, etc...), it should provide the same rows of data in the same format.

Current LINQ Query:

```
            ViewFullRecipeGrouping = (
                from data in ViewRecipeSummary
                group data by data.RecipeName into recipeGroup
                let fullIngredientGroups = recipeGroup.GroupBy(x => x.IngredientName)
                select new ViewFullRecipe()
                {
                    RecipeName = recipeGroup.Key,
                    RecipeIngredients = (
                        from ingredientGroup in fullIngredientGroups
                        select new GroupIngredient()
                        {
                            IngredientName = ingredientGroup.Key,
                        }
                    ).ToList(),
                    ViewGroupRecipes = (

            // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO ADD MY CODE SO THAT I CAN USE THE RESULT BELOW
            let a = .....
            // BUT I HAVE NO CLUE HOW TO PERFORM SUCH A QUERY HERE

                        select new GroupRecipe()
                        {
            // USE THE RESULTS FOUND TO GENERATE MY RECIPE GROUP
            // BASED ON THE RESULTS FOUND ABOVE
            RecipeName = a.key

                        }).ToList(),
                }).ToList();
```

Something like:

```
                    let a = ViewRecipeSummary.GroupBy(x => x.RecipeName)
                        .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.IngredientName == recipeGroup.Key))
                        .Select(g => new ViewRecipe()
                            {
                                RecipeName = g.Key,
                                IngredientName = g.Select(x => x.IngredientName)
                            })
```

But this returns a List and I need to return it broken down into the same structure.

Here are the classes used:

```
    public class GroupRecipe
    {
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        public List<GroupIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public GroupRecipe() { }
        public GroupRecipe(string _recipeName, List<GroupIngredient> _ingredients)
        {
            RecipeName = _recipeName;
            Ingredients = _ingredients;
        }
    }

   public class GroupIngredient
    {
        public string IngredientName { get; set; }
        public double UnitWeight { get; set; }
        public double TotalWeight { get; set; }

        public GroupIngredient() { }
        public GroupIngredient(string _IngredientName, double _UnitWeight, double _TotalWeight)
        {
            IngredientName = _IngredientName;
            UnitWeight = _UnitWeight;
            TotalWeight = _TotalWeight;
        }
    }
    public class ViewFullRecipe
    {
        public string RecipeName { get; set; }
        public List<GroupIngredient> RecipeIngredients { get; set; }
        public List<GroupRecipe> ViewGroupRecipes { get; set; }

        public ViewFullRecipe() { }
        public ViewFullRecipe(string _RecipeName, List<GroupIngredient> _RecipeIngredients, List<GroupRecipe> _ViewGroupRecipes)
        {
            RecipeName = _RecipeName;
            RecipeIngredients = _RecipeIngredients;
            ViewGroupRecipes = _ViewGroupRecipes;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume you are using an ORM. Which one and how did you generate the ORM mappings? Usually ORM mappings will give you associations (which are properties on the actually mapped classes).
Please include your database model classes.

Comment: If you just want to select with recipes with ingredient "A", your query is too complex. It can be done a lot easier.

Comment: I am not using ORM and there is no database (per-say), it is a collection of data in the format of List<ViewRecipe>.

As for it being to complex, I am not sure what you mean, that is a pre-existing query that does a lot of stuff, I just need to insert into there (where I commented) the new part which is what I am asking for help on.

Comment: Ok, I understand. BTW, I didn't use pure linq to get your result.

Comment: anything that helps is useful at this point for me ... I am lost :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I did understand your question, following code should work.
as others say, I do think your query is complex, where it does not need to be
I think you probably do not want to change what has been working,
I just keep it unchanged

```
var viewFullRecipeGrouping =
(
    from data in viewRecipeSummary
    group data by data.RecipeName
    into recipeGroup
    let fullIngredientGroups = recipeGroup.GroupBy(x => x.IngredientName)
    select new ViewFullRecipe()
        {
            RecipeName = recipeGroup.Key,
            RecipeIngredients =
                (
                    from ingredientGroup in fullIngredientGroups
                    select
                        new GroupIngredient
                            {
                                IngredientName = ingredientGroup.Key,
                                UnitWeight = ingredientGroup.Average(r => r.UnitWeight),
                                TotalWeight = ingredientGroup.Sum(r => r.TotalWeight)
                            }
                ).ToList(),

            ViewGroupRecipes =
                (
                    from recipeName in
                        viewRecipeSummary.GroupBy(x => x.IngredientName)
                                            .Where(g => fullIngredientGroups.Any(f => f.Key == g.Key))
                                            .SelectMany(g => g.Select(i => i.RecipeName))
                                            .Distinct()
                    select new GroupRecipe()
                        {
                            RecipeName = recipeName,
                            Ingredients =
                                viewRecipeSummary.Where(v => v.RecipeName == recipeName)
                                                    .GroupBy(i => i.IngredientName)
                                                    .Select(
                                                        g => new GroupIngredient
                                                            {
                                                                IngredientName = g.Key,
                                                                UnitWeight = g.Sum(i => i.UnitWeight),
                                                                TotalWeight = g.Average(i => i.TotalWeight)
                                                            }).ToList()
                        }
                ).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't compile due to the last .Select(

Comment: yea? strange, it works fine for me, I uploaded my test program, maybe you can tell how it is different from yours

Comment: also, once try this program, could you give me the exception as well?

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BakeryCorner.Client.Presentation.Print.GroupIngredient>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BakeryCorner.Client.Presentation.Print.GroupIngredient>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: ah... my classes will be different to yours, as I just fake them. you may adjust the code according to your classes

Comment: Let me post my actual classes, this would help I am sure (sorry). I am sure it is just an easy matter of adjusting but honestly, I just don't see it ... I will update the initial post in 60 seconds

Comment: Fixed it, missing one ToList(), try now. the property RecipeIngredients  is a List<> in your code, so we need a ToList() for the last Select

Comment: I have added all the base classes to the initial post.  
FYI =  public List<GroupRecipe> ViewRecipeGrouping

Comment: Now there is a compile error on the .ToList()

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BakeryCorner.Client.Presentation.Print.ViewFullRecipe>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BakeryCorner.Client.Presentation.Print.GroupRecipe>'

Comment: It all make sense now once you upload you classes, try now

Comment: Ok it compiles but the results are odd if I add other test data (probably a mistake on my end, I have some data where a RecipeName==IngredientName so you could have something like (A,F & A,Z as data pairs and then everything goes nuts), I am going to toy with it and see if I can figure it out ... not sure if you'll still be around tomorrow but I'll post my results. thanks for all the help.

Comment: Question - what if I wanted to add another field to ViewRecipeSummary and GroupIngredient() like IngredientQuantity. Currently the .Select(i => i.IngredientName) only gets IngridentName ... how could I add this?

Comment: My fault, I wasn't very clear there - take a look at the updated post for ViewRecipe and GroupIngredient classes. Each row can now have a weight associated with that ingredient (how much of that ingredient is needed in that recipe). This isn't a count OF ingredients but instead a count of amount PER ingredient

Comment: I was looking to do something like this:  
IngredientName = i,  
UnitWeight = ingredientGroup.Min(x => x.UnitWeight),  
TotalWeight = ingredientGroup.Sum(x => x.TotalWeight)

Obviously this isn't working (just trying to show an example of what I am trying to do).

Comment: Hi J, you are on the right track I think, what you think of, is same to what I got. check the updated answer. Actaully, there is one thing I didn't understand. why are there multiple rows for same ingredent for same recipe? should a recipe only have one ingredent once?

Comment: The way it works (legacy application, not by choice), you have many orders of a recipe for different quantities, and this will add new records for that recipe->ingredients. So I group all the recipes and sum the ingredient amounts to get totals at the end of the day of how much of each ingredient per recipe was needed, etc...

Comment: Ok, then maybe I should change Average to Sum, but apart from this, does the answer work?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your recipe group defined like this:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public string RecipeName { get; set; }
    public string IngredientName { get; set; }

    public Recipe() { }
    public Recipe(string _recipeName, string _IngredientName)
    {
        RecipeName = _recipeName;
        IngredientName = _IngredientName;
    }
}

public class RecipeGroup
{
    public string RecipeName{get;set;}
    public List<Recipe> Recipe{get;set;}
}

public class RecipeGroupDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<Recipe>> data;
    public RecipeGroupDictionary()
    {
        data = new Dictionary<string, List<Recipe>>();
    }
    public bool add(Recipe vr)
    {
        this[vr.RecipeName].Add(vr);
        return true;
    }
    public List<Recipe> this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!data.ContainsKey(key))
                data[key] = new List<Recipe>();
            return data[key];
        }
        set
        {
            data[key] = value;
        }
    }
    public ICollection<string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return data.Keys;
        }
    }
    public List<RecipeGroup> getRecipeGroup()
    {
        var result = new List<RecipeGroup>();
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            result.Add(new RecipeGroup { RecipeName = key, Recipe = data[key] });
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arr = new List<Recipe>();
        var recipeGroup = new RecipeGroupDictionary();
        arr.Add(new Recipe{ RecipeName="1", IngredientName="A"});
        arr.Add(new Recipe{ RecipeName="1", IngredientName="B"});
        arr.Add(new Recipe{ RecipeName="1", IngredientName="C"});
        arr.Add(new Recipe { RecipeName = "2", IngredientName = "B" });
        arr.Add(new Recipe { RecipeName = "2", IngredientName = "C" });
        arr.Add(new Recipe { RecipeName = "3", IngredientName = "A" });
        arr.Add(new Recipe { RecipeName = "3", IngredientName = "X" });
        arr.Add(new Recipe { RecipeName = "3", IngredientName = "Y" });

        var rnset = from row in arr
                    where row.IngredientName == "A"
                    select row.RecipeName;
        var result = (from row in arr
                      where rnset.Contains(row.RecipeName) && recipeGroup.add(row) //Won't be executed if the first condition is false.
                      select row ).ToArray(); //To array is List<Recipe>, if you don't want recipe group you can remove all the recipe dictionary related.
        foreach (var key in recipeGroup.Keys)
        {
            foreach(var recipe in recipeGroup[key])
                Console.WriteLine("RN:{0}, IA:{1}", recipe.RecipeName, recipe.IngredientName);
        }                      
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't help as I need to embed this into my existing query and you are just doing it externally.